# How to stop scrolling listview above first Item?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

My Query is in my `ListView` let say if I scroll to 1st position that is fine but now my `ListView` scrolls beyond that also like my fisrt item will also go down and there is no item before first item so blank screen comes which is looking very bad i hope, i have described well can anybody look into this.

Comment: nop :), you need to explain this in more details and maybe provide as with a screen shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this issue in Galaxy S while over other devices this behaviour is not followed. So I think some device manufacturers have modified their OS and we can't do anything in this case.

Comment: i have used baseadapter is that creating problem?

Comment: @Amol have you tested it on any other device

Comment: i think you are right Vineet but just in case can we solve this problem?

Comment: BaseAdapter is surely not a problem. You should check it over other devices.

Comment: I don't think so that we can fix it as we have no access as a developer.

Comment: Adil and Vineet you both are right i checkd on other device it is working fine still can we solve that problem or let it be just as it is as i have seen their default listview for e.g. the setting screen also behaves the same i dont know why they have did that but i am sure it is not looking good   THANKS VINEET